# How can I compare each element in first list with whole elements in the second list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, comparison

I'm very new to python, so I need your help . I have csv file contains:

```
  Name           Movie_title            Comments
  Mark           toy story                love
  Sam            Grumpy Old Men           cool 
  Mark           Grumpy Old Men           Hate it
  Sam            toy story                didn't like it
```

I create a list contains only name without duplicate:
names = ['Mark,Sam']
 so what I want to create a text file with movie_title(e.g, toy story.txt) contains all the comments in that movie

### toy story.txt

Mark  --  toy story          (love the movie)
Sam    --  toy story         (didn't like it)

### Grumpy Old Men.txt

Sam   --  Grumpy Old Men     (cool)
Mark   -- Grumpy Old Men     (Hate it)

```
with open('data.csv', 'rt') as f:
 reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
  next(reader)# skip header
  for row in reader:
    for name in names:
       if name == row[0]:
         for i in row[0]:
          txt = open(os.path.join(dir_name, names + ".txt"),'w+')
          newlist.append(name+row[2])
          txt.write(newlist)
```

any idea !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit simpler. Because each line has the fields name, movie and comment (row[0], row[1] and row[2], respectively), you can just directly write everything from the fetched line:

```
#!/bin/python
import csv
with open('data.csv', 'rt') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
  next(reader)# skip header
  for row in reader:
    with open(row[1]+".txt","a") as mov:
      mov.write(row[0]+" -- "+row[1]+" ("+row[2]+")\n")
```